# How to make a setup/install for remote msi

Tags: ant, wix, windows-installer

I would want to make a setup which allows to install a remote MSI package.

The trade platform that i use does not allow to download too heavy files - my MSI package is too heavy.

So i am obliged to use a "light" setup which is capable of downloading and of executing my remote MSI package.

For information my MSI package is generated from ANT file with WIX technology.

Any ideas on the way of taking itself there to make this setup ?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer that I can give depends on some assumptions:

1. That you can install an agent on the client systems.
2. That the client is permanently connected to the internet and can get to the remote MSI file, and the same applies if it's an intra-company network situation.

If you can't download the MSI (and "push" installs don't work anyway) then get an agent program onto each client system somehow, which installs the MSI file using your HTTP:// web site as the location of the MSI file, the equivalent of msiexec /i http://server/share/package.msi

This is effectively what group policy and so on do in corporate networks, the MSI being on a share rather than an internet location.

The other alternative if you can download MSI files with your own code is again to have an agent program on the client machine that explicitly downloads the MSI to a permanent location (NOT temp internet files location) and simply installs it with MsiInstallProduct or equivalent, and "how to download a file" is an internet question rather than a Windows Installer question.